# How to Make any Words into Autoit Commands - Hotstringset Alternative

Tags: autoit

How can i Make any words into Autoit Commands?

This Code Works only if i type a Keyboard Hotkey combination, (but i want to type a word to execute the Autoit code.)

HotKeySet Example:

```
HotKeySet (“{F1}”, “calc”)

Func calc()
Local $iPID = ShellExecute (“calc.exe”)
EndFunc
```

Is there a Hotstringset Alternative.

i now in autohotkey you can make any words into Commands.

Autohotkey Languages example:

if i type calc it will execute the Autohotkey code.

```
:*:calc::
run calc.exe
return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With this you can make any words into Autoit Commands.**

Step 1 - You can Download the HotStringSet.zip File Here. (included with the HotString.au3) [HotKeySet vs HotStringSet](http://autoitclipboardlauncher.com/hotkeyset-vs-hotstringset/)

Step 2 - Unzip it + Copy manually the HotString.au3 to path C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\Include

Step 3 - Now your are ready to use HotStringSet in any Autoit Script.

[image]

You can Type on your keyboard any text, for example in Wordpad : Type calc+Space and it will run the Calculator and if you Type kbc+Space it will replace the text kbc into keyboard control and if you Type pi+Space it will replace the text pi into Symbol pi.

Write this Autoit Code.

```
#include <HotString.au3>

HotKeySet ('{F1}', 'quit')

HotStringSet('kbc{SPACE}', replace1)
HotStringSet('pi{SPACE}', replace2)
HotStringSet('calc{SPACE}', replace3)

Func quit()
Exit
EndFunc

Func replace1()
;MsgBox(0,'','You did typed kbc! :)')
send ('{BS 4}keyboard control ') ; replace [kbc] into [keyboard control]
EndFunc

Func replace2()
;MsgBox(0,'','You did typed pi! :)')
send ('{BS 3}{ASC 960} ') ; replace [pi] into [symbol p]
EndFunc

Func replace3()
;MsgBox(0,'','You did typed calc! :)')
Local $iPID = ShellExecute ('calc.exe') ; If you type calc it wil run the application calculator.
EndFunc

While 1
Sleep(10)
WEnd
```